# Not able to view GUI screen in Ubuntu after installing in VMware Workstation 7

Tags: gui, boot

I have installed VMWare Workstation 7.1.4 on a Intel Core 2 Duo Machine running on Windows 7 OS.

I downloaded the DVD image ubuntu-11.04-dvd-i386 from the ubuntu website and installed it on the VMWare workstation.

Gave all the default parameters for Hard Disk space allocation (20 GB) Memory (1 GB) etc. in VMware.

After the installation finished, the ubuntu terminal came on showing:

"

Ubuntu 11.04 ubuntu tty5

ubuntu login:

"

Irrespective of whatever I do, I am unable to make it boot up in the GUI mode.

Please help. It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com.

Comment: not able to post a question in ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Comment: Got the answer... Installed the package xinit "sudo apt-get install xinit" and now the Xserver is launching during the boot up process

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer... Installed the package xinit `sudo apt-get install xinit` and now the Xserver is launching during the boot up process – Dpmishra Sep 14 '11 at 20:20

Answered by OP in comments